# NVIDIA GTX650 Ti 1 GB, nvidia-drivers, boot udev fail on gentoo

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia-graphics-card, gentoo, udev

I have an Asus H97 Plus motherboard with i7 4790 proc, 16gb ram, samsung ssd, western digital hdd and a Gigabyte nVidia GTX650 Ti 1GB videocard.

I have just installed a Gentoo on it (kernel: gentoo-16.1).. everything seems to work, except of the videocard. I compiled Nouveau cards into the kernel (i didnt compiled nvidia and nvidia riva framebuffers) and installed nvidia-drivers-340.32.

lspci -k shows the card (nVidia Corporation GK106 (GeForce-GTX 650 Ti)) and says

```
  kernel module in use: nouveau
  kernel modules: nvidia
```

When i type:

```
 modprobe nvidia
```

It SOMETIMES says "No such device", SOMETIMES says nothing like it was okay, and if i type it several times it crashes with an infinite loop of trying something with system-udevd..

If i don't blacklist nvidia in /etc/modprobe.d/nvidia.conf, then boot hangs at "waiting for uevents to be processed"

I use initramfs and grub.. kde works with nouveau, and glxinfo says something is rendering.. but sometimes kde freezes and lags like hell (after a day idle in lockup for example) and i think that using nouveau with an nvidia card is not the healthiest way of living:)

I would appreciate any help!
Thank you in advance,
Adam

I could copy the content of the make.conf if it made sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a big problem here is that you're trying to use both the nvidia and nouveau drivers.  You really have to pick one, as using two drivers for the same card tends to lead to all manner of unpredictable conflicts.  Nouveau is the open source community driver for NVidia cards, while the nvidia-driver is the official binary blob driver from NVidia.  While using the binary blob is not 100% headache free (occasionally the installer will overwrite files that can be fun to hunt down to fix), it is generally regarded as being more capable when it comes to things like 3D acceleration and general modern gameplay.

Blacklisting one or the other should be enough, and it sounds like that has been your experience.

Comment: The nvidia driver state of affairs is something that you'd hardly be the first person to pull hair out over before finding your way.  Linus himself has berated NVidia publicly about the issues surrounding the binary blob.  In lieu of an open-source alternative that remains as feature rich as the binary driver, however, there's not much we can do but learn to find our way around an awkward situation.